# Spark/Scala: join dataframes when id is nested in an array of structs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark's MlLib DataFrame ALS functionality on Spark 2.2.0. I had to run my userId and itemId fields through an StringIndexer to get things going

The method 'recommendForAllUsers' returns the following schema

```
root
 |-- recommendations: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- itemIdIndex: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rating: double (nullable = true)
 |-- userIdIndex: string (nullable = true)
```

This is perfect for my needs (would love not to flatten it) but I need to replace userIdIndex and itemIdIndex with their actual value

for the userIdIndex was ok (I couldn't simply reverse it with IndexToString as the ALS FITTING seems to erase the link between index and value):

```
df.join(df2, df2("userIdIndex")===df("userIdIndex"), "left")
      .select(df2("userId"), df("recommendations"))
```

where df2 looks like this:

```
+------------------+--------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|            userId|              itemId|    rating|userIdIndex|itemIdIndex|
+------------------+--------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|glorified-consumer|          item-22302|       3.0|       15.0|        4.0|
```

the result is this schema:

```
root
 |-- userId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- recommendations: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- itemIdIndex: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rating: float (nullable = true)
```

**QUESTION:** for itemIdIndex, being inside an array of structures.

Comment: did you try using `array_contains`?

Comment: not exactly sure how to use it with join to be honest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `explode` the `array` so that `struct` is only remained as

```
val tempdf2 = df2.withColumn("recommendations", explode('recommendations))
```

which should leave you with `schema` as

```
root
 |-- userdId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- recommendations: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- itemIdIndex: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rating: string (nullable = true)
```

Do the same for `df` (the first `dataframe`)

Then after that you can join them as

```
tempdf1.join(tempdf2, tempdf1("recommendations.itemIndex") === tempdf2("recommendations.itemIndex"))
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot in a bit, mind if I ask you how to un-explode (return it to the same schema) after I join them

Comment: @javaNoober Were you able to get the solution for your question. Pls, share if you got answer.